# OpenSSL: Read an EC-key, then write it again, and it's different

Tags: c++, openssl, private-key, elliptic-curve

I wrote a wrapper for OpenSSL that supports ECC. I'm trying to read a private key that I generated with

```
openssl ecparam -name secp384r1 -genkey -noout -out privkey.pem
```

And compare it with what OpenSSL would produce after reading the key into a `EVP_PKEY` and `EC_KEY` and printing it again into a string. The results after reading are not the same.

In short:

1. Read a key
2. Save it to `EVP_PKEY`
3. Write it again

And the results don't match. My program is quite big, so [I produced an MCVE that demonstrates the problem](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/363df1964f7f65b7).

My suspicion is that the problem happens because I'm reading to an `EC_KEY`, then writing from `EVP_PKEY`, which is generic. I'm guessing here because the input says it's EC, but the output doesn't say that. I'm not sure how to resolve this, because I don't see a way to write directly from an `EC_KEY` to a file (bio object). Is my assessment correct?

Please advise.

---

EDIT:
I was asked to put the whole code here in the comments, so there you go:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

EC_KEY* ecKey = nullptr;
EVP_PKEY* pkey = nullptr;

void setPrivateKeyFromPEM(const std::string& pemkey)
{
    pkey = EVP_PKEY_new();

    BIO* bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

    int bio_write_ret = BIO_write(
        bio, static_cast<const char*>(pemkey.c_str()), pemkey.size());
    if (bio_write_ret <= 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("error1");
    }

    if (!PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(bio, &pkey, NULL, NULL)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("error1.5");
    }

    EC_KEY* eckey_local = EVP_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY(pkey);

    if (!eckey_local) {
        throw std::runtime_error("error2");
    } else {
        ecKey = eckey_local;
        EC_KEY_set_asn1_flag(ecKey, OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE);
    }
}

std::string getPrivateKeyAsPEM()
{
    if (!pkey) {
        throw std::runtime_error("error3");
    }

    BIO* outbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

    if (!PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey(outbio, pkey, NULL, NULL, 0, 0,
                                  NULL)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("error4");
    }

    std::string keyStr;
    int         priKeyLen = BIO_pending(outbio);
    keyStr.resize(priKeyLen);
    BIO_read(outbio, (void*)&(keyStr.front()), priKeyLen);
    return keyStr;
}

int main()
{
    std::string expectedPrivKey =
        "-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
        "MIGkAgEBBDBNK0jwKqqf8zkM+Z2l++9r8bzdTS/XCoB4N1J07dPxpByyJyGbhvIy\n"
        "1kLvY2gIvlmgBwYFK4EEACKhZANiAAQvPxAK2RhvH/k5inDa9oMxUZPvvb9fq8G3\n"
        "9dKW1tS+ywhejnKeu/48HXAXgx2g6qMJjEPpcTy/DaYm12r3GTaRzOBQmxSItStk\n"
        "lpQg5vf23Fc9fFrQ9AnQKrb1dgTkoxQ=\n"
        "-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

    setPrivateKeyFromPEM(expectedPrivKey);
    // compare priv key
    {
        std::string privKeyRead = getPrivateKeyAsPEM();
        std::cout << privKeyRead << std::endl;
        std::cout<<expectedPrivKey<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to post your code here, not on some site you link to.

Comment: Yes, your assessment is correct. If you need to write EC_KEY to bio then OpenSSL 1.1.0 supports this functionality. See [PEM_write_bio_ECPrivateKey](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/PEM_write_bio_ECPrivateKey.html).

Comment: @MarekKlein So it's impossible to get this to work in OpenSSL 1.0.2?

Comment: unknown curve name (nistp256)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PEM_write_bio_ECPrivateKey` is available in OpenSSL 1.0.2 too, only the documentation is missing.

The stored key is the same, the difference is only in encoding.

The tag `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` signifies a PEM-encoded ASN.1 format.

The tag `-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----` signifies a PEM-encoded ANSI X9.62 key.

Compare: [**key 1**](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#3081B6020100301006072A8648CE3D020106052B8104002204819E30819B02010104304D2B48F02AAA9FF3390CF99DA5FBEF6BF1BCDD4D2FD70A8078375274EDD3F1A41CB227219B86F232D642EF636808BE59A164036200042F3F100AD9186F1FF9398A70DAF683315193EFBDBF5FABC1B7F5D296D6D4BECB085E8E729EBBFE3C1D7017831DA0EAA3098C43E9713CBF0DA626D76AF7193691CCE0509B1488B52B64969420E6F7F6DC573D7C5AD0F409D02AB6F57604E4A314) vs. [**key 2**](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#3081A402010104304D2B48F02AAA9FF3390CF99DA5FBEF6BF1BCDD4D2FD70A8078375274EDD3F1A41CB227219B86F232D642EF636808BE59A00706052B81040022A164036200042F3F100AD9186F1FF9398A70DAF683315193EFBDBF5FABC1B7F5D296D6D4BECB085E8E729EBBFE3C1D7017831DA0EAA3098C43E9713CBF0DA626D76AF7193691CCE0509B1488B52B64969420E6F7F6DC573D7C5AD0F409D02AB6F57604E4A314). Notice key2 doesn't contain the key type OID, the key itself is identical.

To write the EC key format, just use this:

```
    if (!PEM_write_bio_ECPrivateKey(outbio, ecKey, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL)) {
```

[coliru-demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/096b0967b3d76ab2)

Answer (score 3):

Although the outputs don't match exactly, they actually represent the same key.

Your code outputs the following:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIG2AgEAMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAiBIGeMIGbAgEBBDBNK0jwKqqf8zkM+Z2l
++9r8bzdTS/XCoB4N1J07dPxpByyJyGbhvIy1kLvY2gIvlmhZANiAAQvPxAK2Rhv
H/k5inDa9oMxUZPvvb9fq8G39dKW1tS+ywhejnKeu/48HXAXgx2g6qMJjEPpcTy/
DaYm12r3GTaRzOBQmxSItStklpQg5vf23Fc9fFrQ9AnQKrb1dgTkoxQ=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGkAgEBBDBNK0jwKqqf8zkM+Z2l++9r8bzdTS/XCoB4N1J07dPxpByyJyGbhvIy
1kLvY2gIvlmgBwYFK4EEACKhZANiAAQvPxAK2RhvH/k5inDa9oMxUZPvvb9fq8G3
9dKW1tS+ywhejnKeu/48HXAXgx2g6qMJjEPpcTy/DaYm12r3GTaRzOBQmxSItStk
lpQg5vf23Fc9fFrQ9AnQKrb1dgTkoxQ=
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

If you look closely at the first key printed, which is the one imported/exported by your code, it is labeled "BEGIN PRIVATE KEY" instead of "BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY".  It also starts with `MIG2AgEAMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAiBIGe` but after that it is identical to the original key.  In fact, if you put both PEMs in files and run `openssl ec -in {filename} -text`, both will output the same thing:

```
read EC key
Private-Key: (384 bit)
priv:
    4d:2b:48:f0:2a:aa:9f:f3:39:0c:f9:9d:a5:fb:ef:
    6b:f1:bc:dd:4d:2f:d7:0a:80:78:37:52:74:ed:d3:
    f1:a4:1c:b2:27:21:9b:86:f2:32:d6:42:ef:63:68:
    08:be:59
pub: 
    04:2f:3f:10:0a:d9:18:6f:1f:f9:39:8a:70:da:f6:
    83:31:51:93:ef:bd:bf:5f:ab:c1:b7:f5:d2:96:d6:
    d4:be:cb:08:5e:8e:72:9e:bb:fe:3c:1d:70:17:83:
    1d:a0:ea:a3:09:8c:43:e9:71:3c:bf:0d:a6:26:d7:
    6a:f7:19:36:91:cc:e0:50:9b:14:88:b5:2b:64:96:
    94:20:e6:f7:f6:dc:57:3d:7c:5a:d0:f4:09:d0:2a:
    b6:f5:76:04:e4:a3:14
ASN1 OID: secp384r1
NIST CURVE: P-384
writing EC key
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGkAgEBBDBNK0jwKqqf8zkM+Z2l++9r8bzdTS/XCoB4N1J07dPxpByyJyGbhvIy
1kLvY2gIvlmgBwYFK4EEACKhZANiAAQvPxAK2RhvH/k5inDa9oMxUZPvvb9fq8G3
9dKW1tS+ywhejnKeu/48HXAXgx2g6qMJjEPpcTy/DaYm12r3GTaRzOBQmxSItStk
lpQg5vf23Fc9fFrQ9AnQKrb1dgTkoxQ=
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The extra part at the beginning is metadata from exporting a `EVP_PKEY` key stating that the key is an EC key.

Had you instead exported the `EC_KEY` directly using `PEM_write_bio_ECPrivateKey(outbio, ecKey, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL)` the output would be exactly the same.